# You don't have permission to access /admin/add.php on this server

Tags: php, mysql, summernote

My code working fine in localhost but after uploading in server i am getting this error -> Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /admin/add.php on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

searched about it but didnt get a proper solution asked in fb grps as-well. and one more thing there is no .htaccess file in root folder. tried to add .htaccess file in server but didn't work as-well. I am using summernote in textarea previously i used tinymce but getting same error. its work fine without summernote/tinymce . textarea type is mediumtext

add.php

```
<?php
include_once('../includes/config.php');

    //if form has been submitted process it
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );

        //collect form data
        extract($_POST);

        //very basic validation
        if($category_id ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please select the category id.';
        }

        if($cam_unique_id ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the cam unique id.';
        }

        if($cam_features ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter cam feature.';
        }

        if(!isset($error)){

            try {

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO cam_details (category_id,subcategory_id,cam_unique_id,cam_name,brand,cam_features,cam_spec_t1,cam_spec_t2,cam_spec_t3,cam_spec_t4,cam_spec_t5,cam_spec_t6,cam_spec1,cam_spec2,cam_spec3,cam_spec4,cam_spec5,cam_spec6) VALUES 
                (:category_id, :subcategory_id, :cam_unique_id, :cam_name, :brand, :cam_features, :cam_spec_t1, :cam_spec_t2, :cam_spec_t3, :cam_spec_t4, :cam_spec_t5, :cam_spec_t6,:cam_spec1, :cam_spec2, :cam_spec3, :cam_spec4, :cam_spec5, :cam_spec6)') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':category_id' => $category_id,
                    ':subcategory_id' => $subcategory_id,
                    ':cam_unique_id' => $cam_unique_id,
                    ':cam_name' => $cam_name,
                    ':brand' => $brand,
                    ':cam_features' => $cam_features,
                    ':cam_spec_t1' => $cam_spec_t1,
                    ':cam_spec_t2' => $cam_spec_t2,
                    ':cam_spec_t3' => $cam_spec_t3,
                    ':cam_spec_t4' => $cam_spec_t4,
                    ':cam_spec_t5' => $cam_spec_t5,
                    ':cam_spec_t6' => $cam_spec_t6,
                    ':cam_spec1' => $cam_spec1,
                    ':cam_spec2' => $cam_spec2,
                    ':cam_spec3' => $cam_spec3,
                    ':cam_spec4' => $cam_spec4,
                    ':cam_spec5' => $cam_spec5,
                    ':cam_spec6' => $cam_spec6

                ));

                //redirect to index page
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }

    }

    //check for any errors
    if(isset($error)){
        foreach($error as $error){
            echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Did you check the file/folder permission on your files and folders in server?

Comment: ask the host...

Comment: `Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` just means you don't have an error document for 403 set up and can be ignored.  Check the web server error log, but most likely a permissions error.

Comment: gave 777 permission to add.php still getting error @Devon

Comment: @IamSrkfan, did you check the server log?  Just because you have 777 on add.php doesn't mean the directory is readable by the web server or that there isn't another error present.

Comment: ok, i dont have much knowledge about server sir @Devon . btw i have added the add.php coding can you check once please.

Comment: Then you need to hire someone or reach out to someone who does.  This has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: thanks @Devon sir. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add includes folder in admin directory and change the coding to

```
include_once('includes/config.php');
```